# How to sort plotly stacked bar graph in r by y value?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I've got [this graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60289954/select-top-3-parents-groups-in-plotly-graph-using-r/60290947#60290947) and I want it to appear in `Sam` - `Jhon` - `Paul` order because that's going from highest to lowest cost, somebody could tell me how to order it by cost? Tried using code below in `layout` section but it didn't word.

```
 layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Cost'), 
        xaxis = list(title = 'Parent',
                     categoryorder = "array",
                     categoryarray = ~cost), 
                     barmode = 'stack')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to use the order of `top_3$parent` in your `categoryarray` instead of `cost`, as follows:

```
layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Cost'), 
       xaxis = list(title = 'Parent',
               categoryorder = "array",
               categoryarray = top_3$parent), 
               barmode = 'stack')
```

So, using the full plotting code:

```
plot_ly(sample[sample$parent %in% top_3$parent,], 
        x = ~parent, y = ~cost, type = 'bar', color = ~topic) %>%
        layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Cost'), 
               xaxis = list(title = 'Parent', 
                            categoryorder = "array", 
                            categoryarray = top_3$parent), 
                            barmode = 'stack') %>%
        config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

You should get the following plot:

[image]